# Unable to browse Asp.net core web api through browser after hosting in windows container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-machine, asp.net-core-2.2, docker-desktop

I’m trying to host Asp.net core 3.1 api in  a windows container on my windows machine and would like to connect to it via localhost or IP address.
I am using Docker Desktop community edition of version 2.2.0.3  and Windows 10 Pro.

Please find my Dockerfile template as below :

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY  TweetBook/TweetBook.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore


COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish TweetBook/TweetBook.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish



FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1903
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env /app/publish/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TweetBook.dll"]
```

I am able to build the image.  Please find the details in below screenshot :
[image]

Successfully able to run the image as below using **docker run -p 9006:80 aspnetdocker/tweetbook**
[image]

When i am trying to browse the api using  http://locallhost:9006/api/v1/posts  i am getting **locallhost’s server IP address could not be found.**

[image]

I have tried to browse it using IP address instead of localhost but it's not working. Can someone help me what is missing here.

Comment: Please share your docker file. and run docker ps in your CLI and screen shot the container running. Also your screen shot shows port 9006 being used on local host where your container is using 9004?

Comment: @Hawkzey : Please find the updated post.

Comment: I feel like this is a mapping issue for localhost to your docker containers IP. this works fine for me, you could try running (param: -it) in your docker run command then use the ip of your docker container instead of localhost. are you using the default NAT adapter?

Comment: Could also try changing to use Linux containers, its an easy switch with docker desktop. and see if it works there.

Comment: Tried to switch to Linux container and give a build but getting error like : image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform.